# flex Dynamic column grouping using Hirarchical/tree data structure

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

Does anybody tried Dynamic column grouping using Hirarchical/tree data structure in Flex advanced datagrid ? 
is it possible to create a column header dynamically and so the datagrid column with using certain datafield using dataprovider dat.

Any help would be great.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [top answer](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=advdatagrid_06.html) of Google seems appropriate: it's the functionality you search already solved there?

Comment: i need to dynamically create the group of header not the display of the tree data in datagrid. I am creating header grouping and whole adg in as3 dynamically. I need certain data structure that we can read and create header dynamically. Hope this can help to understand what i am asking :(.

Comment: Grouping columns it's covered here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/advdatagrid_09.html#290206. You can access the entire flex library (and thus AdvancedDataGrid) with ActionScript3. Simply import the appropriate namespaces.